# How to handle None values in my function?

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with a exercise. It says this.

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
> You can return the answer in any order.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
> Output: [0,1]

I have tried to do this:

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
tarjet = 9  
def return_index(nums,tarjet):
    index_positions = []
    for i, num in enumerate(nums, tarjet):
        while i == 0:
            i += 1
            if i == 0:
                obtain_index =  num[i] + num[i]
                if obtain_index == tarjet:
                    index_positions.append(num[i])
                    return index_positions
            else:
                obtain_index  = num[i - 1] + num[i]
                if obtain_index == tarjet:
                    index_positions.append(num[i - 1] , num[i])
                    return index_positions
            
first_index_list = return_index(nums, tarjet)
print(first_index_list)
```

But the output give me this: None. What did I do incorrectly?

Comment: You are starting with `i == 9`. The `while` loop never gets entered. I don't think you want to pass `tarjet` to `enumerate`.

Comment: `enumerate(nums, tarjet)` doesn't make real sense.

Comment: Best to use hash/dictionary to make one loop - O(n). Besides the pointed ^^^ answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is too broken to try to write a meaningful answer.

Comment: Do you know how to make the 'i' in the index of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a much faster solution, especially if the number of values is large.  I'll just give the outline, since this appears to be an exercise, and programming it yourself is good for you.

Create a dictionary in which the elements of `nums` are the keys, and their associated value is their index in the array.  Then iterate through this dictionary, and for each `value, index` in the dictionary, see if `target - value` is also in the dictionary.  Ignore the case that `target = 2 * value`, since you'll just get back the value you just started with.

This makes the problem linear, rather than quadratic.